# How do I stop an image from shrinking after it has reached a certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

My background image is this big:  1920 × 1200

Here is how I am displaying it:

```
html {
    background: url("back.png") no-repeat top left fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This works fine but now I want to be able to make it stop from re-adjust after reaching a certain pre-defined range? Like maybe when the image has shrank to reach 1300 x 500 it should stop.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried a media query?

Comment: I am using media queries for ipad related design but this is slightly difficult because i want this to work the same way across all devices/platforms.

Comment: If you set the background-size to cover, the background image will "cover", doesn't matter if you set max-height, height or anything else. You should do this with an image element, and not a background image, then you'll have options, and it would be cross browser.

Comment: @adeneo can you demo with a fiddle? thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4UgjH/

Comment: that worked can you post as an answer so i can select it!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the `min-width` and `max-width` properties?

When you start messing with the width, make sure you set the height to 100% to maintain the aspect ration.

Comment: The problem with that is that i am using the html selector do achieve this.  if i add a max or min width it will break the content i have displaying.

Comment: This wont work at all with a background image, this is for the element, the background will still scale.